# What value in Python corresponds to `Py_GetPythonHome`? `sys.prefix`?

Tags: python, cpython

[`Py_GetPythonHome`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_GetPythonHome) is a C API.

How do I get the same value within Python?

Is that `sys.base_prefix`? `sys.exec_prefix`? Sth else? I found `sys._home` but this is `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From everything I can tell looking at the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/), `Py_GetPythonHome` holds the value of the environment variable `PYTHONHOME`, if it is set, or the value assigned to it using `Py_SetPythonHome`. If neither `os.environ["PYTHONHOME"]` has been set, `Py_SetPythonHome` called, or the system function `Py_Initialize` has been called, then as of v3.10 its default value is `NULL`.

The `Py_GetPythonHome` function is defined in [`Python/pathconfig.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/pathconfig.c#L361), which is also where [`Py_SetPythonHome`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/pathconfig.c#L256) is defined. The `_PyPathConfig` struct (of which `_Py_path_config` is an instance) contains `wchar_t *home`, which has this [comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/pathconfig.c#L37):

> Set by Py_SetPythonHome() or PYTHONHOME environment variable

So, it looks like the only way you can access `Py_GetPythonHome` is either directly through the C API (as Abdul demonstrates in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73735404)) or via `os.environ["PYTHONHOME"]`, *if* that environment variable has been set.

`sys._home` seems to only be set in virtualenvs - I'm not sure what relation it has to `Py_GetPythonHome`. I haven't yet looked directly into how `sys.base_prefix` and similar attributes are set.

Comment: But how does that answer my question? Do you say you cannot get that value from within Python?

Comment: @Albert That's what I said in the first sentence of the last paragraph - it looks like you can only directly access it from the C API (via `ctypes`, as another answer just showed), or, if it's set, via `os.environ("PYTHONHOME")`. I don't know what relation it has to `sys.base_prefix` and the others - that may be how they're set, but I didn't look at it.

Comment: Ah sorry, this was not clear to me from your answer. But as you say, you don't really know whether I can maybe infer it from some of the others? What do you refer to with "this variable" in your first sentence?

Comment: @Albert I clarified my answer some, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I get the same value within Python?

Well I don't see any option to consume the `Py_GetPythonHome` directly using the `sys` module. My assumption is that `Py_GetPythonHome` might be exposed ***only as C-API***.

To get the same value in python you can consume the C-API via `ctypes` module.

```
>>> from ctypes import pythonapi, c_wchar_p
>>>
>>> home = pythonapi.Py_GetPythonHome
>>> home.argtypes = ()
>>> home.restype = c_wchar_p
>>> home()
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking a bit more to the CPython code, it seems that `Py_SetPythonHome` is deprecated from Python 3.11 on. So maybe it is anyway not a good idea to make much use of it.

Further, you find this ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/38af903506e9b18c6350c1dadcb489f057713f36/Python/pathconfig.c#L235)):

```
    if (_Py_path_config.home != NULL) {
        _Py_path_config.stdlib_dir = _PyMem_RawWcsdup(_Py_path_config.home);
    }
```

And that can be accessed via `sys._stdlib_dir` in Python >=3.11 ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/de33df27aaf930be6a34027c530a651f0b4c91f5/Python/sysmodule.c#L3341)).